# AWS Lambda NodeJS10.x - wkhtmltopdf Unknown application error occurred

Tags: aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf

I've updating our lambda functions from nodejs8 to nodejs10.x and I have several issues with wkhtmltopdf, I'm getting this error when I call the library

> Unknown application error occurred

**Library Implementation**

```
const wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf')
wkhtmltopdf.command = `${process.cwd()}/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
module.exports = wkhtmltopdf
```

**Implementation Code**

```
    try {
      wkhtmltopdf(resultHtml, options, function(error, stream) {
        console.log('Response', error, stream)

        if (error) return reject(error)
        return toArray(stream)
          .then(function(parts) {
            const buffers = parts.map(part =>
              Buffer.isBuffer(part) ? part : Buffer.from(part)
            )
            document.data = Buffer.concat(buffers)
            resolve(document)
          })
          .catch(reject)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Catch error', error)
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am guessing you have to update your dependencies. Share the full error logs.

Comment: I already did, that's the aws lambda error I saw from the cloudwatch.

`Unknown application error occurred`